# Assembly language making a for loop that runs n/10 times

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am a beginner in Assembly Language Programming and I am looking for some help in creating a for loop that runs in n/10 seconds.

I am having trouble understanding how I would convert this Java for loop into an assembly language for loop. 
**N is a value that user enters.** 
**for(i = 1; i<= n; i++)**

*Am I heading in the right direction? 
And if I am not where am I making a mistake?* 
I am just trying to get the loop working and I will worry about run time later.

**CODE:**

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA

number1 DWORD   ?

sum DWORD   ?

prompt1 BYTE    "Enter a number between 1-100", 0

string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)

.CODE

_MainProc PROC

    input   prompt1, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters
    atod    string          ; convert to integer
    mov     ecx, eax    ; store input to memory this is n
    mov     eax, 0  ; //set eax to 0
    mov     edx, 0  //This is sum
    mov ebx, 1      //Create i
    cmp ecx, ebx    //compare i to n
    jnle ecx        //jump when negative or less than ecx
    add edx, ebx    //adds i to sum
    inc ebx         //i++
    jmp ebx         //jump to ebx repeat
_MainProc ENDP

END                             ; end of source code
```

Comment: What the hell?  A fixed amount of real time like `n/10` seconds is a totally different question from a fixed iteration count (running `n/10` times like the title says).  CPUs have variable clock speeds...

Comment: Your edit totally changed the question.  If you want to break out of a loop after n tenths of a second, you could check `rdtsc` every 100 iterations, or set a timer that will run a signal handler which changes a variable.  If you just want to delay, sleep with a `nanosleep` system call or whatever the Windows equivalent is.  You should avoid using a delay loop for anything longer than a microsecond or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to loop by a fraction of something is to add or sub by 10 in the loop.

Instead of doing a division to get the iteration count, do repeated subtraction inside the loop.  Repeated add/sub is normally a terrible way to multiply/divide, but you want to loop that many times anyway so you use *that* as the loop counter.  This is called a "strength reduction" optimization, because division is "stronger" (slower/more expensive) than subtraction.

One way to do this is to count down towards zero and break out of the loop when the counter becomes negative (signed less-than), or alternatively when it crosses zero (unsigned carry).

`atod` returns the result in `eax` so you're clobbering it with `mov eax, 0`.

```
    ... code to get input, and call atod
    ; atod return value in eax = n

    xor    edx, edx       ; sum = edx = 0

    ; loop n/10 times  (integer division truncates towards 0)
@loop:                    ; do {
    add    edx, eax         ; sum += i

    sub    eax, 10          ; i -= 10
    jnc    @loop          ; } while(i didn't wrap around);

    mov    eax, edx      ; eax=sum
```

Or use jg to loop `}while(i>0)`, or `jge` to loop `}while(i>=0)`.  Adding zero is a no-op, so we *can* let the loop run once when `i=0`, but `jg` would be good here if you don't need to support a starting value greater than the largest signed 32-bit integer.  (i.e. if you don't need unsigned).

If you want to loop upwards, you can do that with a compare-and-branch

```
    ... code to get input, and call atod
    ; atod return value in eax = n

    xor    edx, edx       ; sum = edx = 0
    mov    ecx, 1         ;   i = ecx = 1

    ; if the loop might need to run 0 times, test eax,eax / jz to the bottom.
    ; or cmp eax, 10 or whatever.
@loop:                    ; do {
    add    edx, ecx         ; sum += i

    add    ecx, 10          ; i += 10
    cmp    ecx, eax
    jb     @loop          ; } while(i < n);

    mov    eax, edx      ; eax=sum
```

Adjust as desired to do a signed compare, or `jbe` to do `<=`, or whatever.

> in big o notation of n/10.

O(n) complexity classes don't count constant factors, so O(n) = O(n/10).  I'm assuming you mean "runs n/10 times" like you said in the title, not `n` times like in your Java `for` loop, or O(n) times (which would allow any off-by-one errors or constant multipliers).

---

If you want a counter that only increments by 1 in the loop, you could count down the loop-terminating condition (towards zero) and count up another register.  Your Java didn't show the factor of 10 anywhere so IDK where you want it.

Avoid using `div` if possible, [it's about 30x slower than `add`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat).